# How to convert to number month to month name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

In sql database - the data in month is in numbers (1,2,3...12). In my webpage, i would like it to display in month name (Jan, Feb, Mar....Dec). How to convert to number month to month name?

VB.Net

```
   rs = db.ExecuteSelect("SELECT year,month, run_sequence, pay_code, qty, rate, amount,  " & _
                                      "convert(varchar, effective_date,103) as effective_date " & _
                                      "FROM payTable WHERE id='" & id & "'", Session("CnnStr").ToString)
```

UPDATE :
found my solution.

```
DATENAME(mm,DATEADD(mm, month-1,0))  as month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to get Three digit Month short Name based on your Month Number

```
Declare @month int 
set  @month = 1
select  Left(DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @month , -1 )),3);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're selecting month, select DATENAME(mm,month) instead.

Comment: DATENAME(mm,DATEADD(mm, month-1,0))  as month